# HTML Rich Textbox

Tags: javascript, python, http, pylons, widget

I'm writing a web-app using Python and Pylons.  I need a textbox that is rich (ie, provides the ability to bold/underline/add bullets..etc...).  Does anyone know a library or widget I can use?

It doesn't have to be Python/Pylons specific, as it can be a Javascript implementation as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several very mature javascript implementations that are server-framework agnostic:

- http://www.fckeditor.net/
- [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)
- [WMD](http://wmd-editor.com/) (used by SO)

The wikipedia article on [Free HTML editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_HTML_editors) has a good overview, though note that not all are for application embedding.

Answer (score 2):

ExtJS's HtmlEditor was the best I found (license issues aside):

http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.HtmlEditor

ExtJS is a bit heavy-weight, but that HtmlEditor was the most responsive and best-looking out of the box that I found.  It's worth running the output through HTMLTidy, which there are python libraries for.

Answer (score 1):

webkit-gtk is getting very stable, and i believe has python bindings now so technically you could use that (then your text editor merely needs to be `<body contenteditable></body>` and you'd be done.  Unfortunately i'm not sure how complete its bindings are at present