# Change color of one input word in php form

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is a drop down search form, I am looking to change the color of one word in the this.value sentence that is displayed.

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">
<input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value=='We'll steer you in the right direction') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='We'll steer you in the right direction';" value="We'll steer you in the right direction" name="s" id="s" /><br />
```

Im looking to have the word "steer" displayed in a different color.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't, this isn't possible with vanilla select boxes.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create your own control to do that. A "rich text" box would allow you to control the formatting inside your text box, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732429/html-rich-textbox).